# Ansible how to split string in newline

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am running in ansible playbook with:

```
--extra-vars "log_path=/var/logs/a*.log,/repo/log-events-a*.json,repo/user1/log-events-b*.json"
```

as comma separated lines, I want the output in filebeat.yml file as

```yaml
      paths:    
        - /var/logs/a*.log    
        - /repo/log-events-a*.json    
        - /repo/user1/log-events-b*.json
```

I am using jinja2 for filebeat.yml

```yaml
     paths:    
        -  {{ log_path }}
```

And my ansible file testconfigure.yml is

```yaml
      - hosts: localhost    
         gather_facts: no    
      
         vars:    
             log_path: "{{ logpath.replace(',', '\n-')}}"    
         tasks:    
    
          - name: a jija test    
            template:    
              src: /repo/filebeat/filebeat.j2    
              dest : /repo/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```

I am getting the output in filebeat.yml file as:

```yaml
    paths:
     - /var/logs/*.log,/repo/log-events-a*.json,/repo/user1/log-events-b*.json
```

I also tried logpath: `"{{ logpath | regex_replace(',', '\n-') }"` in my playbook, but still getting same output.
How should I try it?

Comment: => `{{ logpath.split(',') }}`. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ansible+split+string

Comment: This didn't work..

Comment: in your extravar you have a mistake,  i think its logpath= and not log_path=

Comment: @Priya: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b7Tp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a j2 file :

```
paths:
{% for log in log_path %}
  - {{ log }}
{% endfor %}
```

playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:    
    log_path: "{{ logpath.split(',') }}"
  tasks:

    - name: templating
      template:
        src: filebeat.j2
        dest: filebeat.yml
```

and the command to call:

```
ansible-playbook yourplaybook.yml --extra-vars "logpath=/var/logs/a*.log,/repo/log-events-a*.json,repo/user1/log-events-b*.json
```

result:

```
paths:
  - /var/logs/a*.log
  - /repo/log-events-a*.json
  - repo/user1/log-events-b*.json
```

if you just want to create a var file, no need to template:

```
- name: create var file
  copy:
    content: "{{ log_path | to_nice_yaml }}"
    dest: filebeat.yml
```

result:

```
paths:
- /var/logs/a*.log
- /repo/log-events-a*.json
- repo/user1/log-events-b*.json
```

Comment: This works!! How to_nice_yaml works? I don't understand from the ansible documentation.

Comment: No nice yaml = yaml  on one  line only